# Unable to build Xamarin Android App after updating Nuget Package

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I updated my app to reference v23 of the compatibility library (Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat version="23.3.0") and can no longer build the app. I get the following errors:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
>   
> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
>   
> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Android project in Visual Studio (Blank project)
2. Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (via nuget)
3. Create file called styles.xml in the values folder with the following text

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
  
</resources>
```

Comment: Did you update other support libs as well? Unrelated: Remove `android:` prefix from `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark`.

Comment: Support libs from Nuget are:

1. id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0"
2. id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" 
3. id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0"
4. id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0"


Those are the latest packages as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, But here is the solution install the latest android sdk ( Android 7 Nouget and img) restart your visual studio or ide, then try installing the nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

Had to uninstall nuget packages then delete zip files and support directories from:

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Xamarin